# NStableview with Images in popover

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cocoa, nstableview

premise that i'm new to developement in macOS.

I have a popover which is called by a button and in this popover i would like to see a list of images contained in a folder on the desktop.

should i use a tableview?

I would like a result [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lLwu.png) :

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjolF.png) is what I have:

Comment: better to copy snippets of code to the question, rather then provide links

Comment: Welcome! Please, take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can use `NSTableView` for this task. Read linked articles from the previous comment, try to implement it and come back in case you'll have issues. Don't forget to include what's not working, what have you done (code), ... then.

Comment: If it's just a set of images, I would suggest looking into `NSStackView`. It's much simpler and designed for just this kind of subview arrangement.